# ReactNative Animated.ScrollView ref TypeScript definition

Tags: typescript, react-native

In a React Native component, I have: `<Animated.ScrollView ref={cardRef} ... />`.

When I hover on top of `ref` I see `(JSX attribute) React.ClassAttributes<Animated.ScrollView>.ref?: React.LegacyRef<Animated.ScrollView> | undefined`, so I create the ref like so `const cardRef = useRef<React.RefObject<Animated.ScrollView> | undefined>(undefined);` but doing `cardRef.current?.scrollTo({ x: newOffset });` gives me a warning for `scrollTo`: `Property 'scrollTo' does not exist on type 'RefObject<ScrollView>'`.

How can I know what the right TS definition of it should be? Is there a way or is it always a guessing game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are *almost* there.  The generic type parameter on `useRef` is for the type that this is a ref to.  In other words, the type of the `.current` property.  You don't need to include `RefObject` in the generic because it already knows that it creates a `RefObject`.  It just needs to know what *type* of `RefObject` it is creating.

Your current types are saying that it is creating a `RefObject` whose `.current` property is a `RefObject` and that ref's `.current` property is the `ScrollView`.

A little trick that you'll find from poking in the type declarations and examining error messages is that `null` is an acceptable value for any element ref.  So you can use `null` as the initial value and you don't have to include  `| undefined` in the type.

You should change:

```
const cardRef = useRef<React.RefObject<Animated.ScrollView> | undefined>(undefined);
```

to:

```
const cardRef = useRef<Animated.ScrollView>(null);
```

Comment: Thanks for this clear and detailed explanation. I updated to just `Animated.ScrollView`, however, now I see a warning for `.current` with "Property 'scrollTo' does not exist on type 'ScrollView'". Although, it seems to exist - https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#scrollto. Please have a look at https://snack.expo.io/@kickbk/ts-animated-scrollview so you can see the warning I'm getting.

Comment: I also believe `typeof` in this case may not be necessary? Regardless, it doesn't change the waning I'm getting.

Comment: Your Expo is showing it as a runtime error too!  But the docs say that the property exists so I don't know what's going on unfortunately.  Re `typeof`, it seemed to be necessary when I was playing with it in CodeSandbox but I was not expecting to need it.  I guess it's not actually necessary.  Classes can be used as both types and values.  You need `typeof` with function components.

Comment: Just realized that you are importing `Animated` from "react-native-reanimated" rather than from "react-native" so maybe that's why it's different.

Comment: If I use a regular, non-animated `ScrollView` from "react-native" then there is no issue.  You can check the docs, typings, and source code for "react-native-reanimated" and see if it's expected behavior that the methods of the underlying `ScrollView` are not exposed.

Comment: Got it!  You need `cardRef.current.getNode().scrollTo({x: 0, y: 300})`.

Comment: Thank you! I'm curious. How did you get it? Where did you find the issue?

Comment: I saw `getNode()` in the autocomplete suggestions for `cardRef.current.` and thought "maybe this will give me access to the underlying element".  But there's actually a lot of methods available in the autocomplete for `cardRef.current.getNode().`!  More than just what's available on the `ScrollView`.